# how to identify record with data conversion error in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes

I have this SQL:

```sql
select * 
--  into #Fifac_temp
from Fifac
Where LBCONCOd = 2050
    and LoteId =  0 and FIFACFecha <= '2017-09-01'
```

which returns 1410 records and this error:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '5 DE' to data type int.
```

How can I delete or browse the record with error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem is either `LBCONCOd` or `LoteId` (because you are comparing those values to integers).  You can try these queries:

```
select LBCONCOd
from t
where try_convert(int, LBCONCOd) is null and LBCONCOd is not null;

select LoteId
from t
where try_convert(int, LoteId) is null and LoteId is not null;
```

Comment: ... try_convert is not recognized, my sql server is 2008 R2

Comment: Thanks ! I still can't "see" what record is with the error, but now I can select without error. I'm usind Select... where LoteId = '0'